# Are new instance of beans property(singleton) is created when we create a prototype bean using the getBean method?

Tags: java, spring

Suppose two classes

```
   @Scope("prototype")
    Class A{
    @Autowired
    private B b;

    }

   @Scope("singleton")
    Class B {

  }
```

And the following method of ApplicationContext is invoked.

```
context.getBean("A")
```

will result in creation of new `A` bean, but will it also create a new `B` bean and inject it or use the existing `B` bean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. Since `B` is Singleton scoped. The lifecycle of `B` bean will always be once per container no matter how many `A`'s reference it.

Answer (score 0):

No. It will be only one instance for class B as it is singleton, but when prototype instances created for A, everything Spring container create proxy for B and assign to new instance of A. By doing so, it is maintaining the properties of singleton and prototype.

But be sure, you need such kind of references.Spring uses `@Lookup` annotation to find the related references.